# Javascript regex for amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex for an amount:

ANY DIGIT + PERIOD (at least zero, no more than one) + ANY DIGIT (at least zero no more than two [if possible, either zero OR two])

What I have is:

```
/^\d+\.\{0,1}+\d{0,2)+$/
```

...obviously not working. Examples of what I'm trying to do:

123 valid

123.00 valid

12.34.5 invalid

123.000 invalid

Trying to match an amount with or without the period. If the period is included, can only be once and no more than two digits after.

Comment: There are usually much better ways to detec a number. `parseFloat` for instance.

Comment: @RikudoSennin `parseFloat` can be used as an attempt to convert a string to a number, possibly resulting in `NaN`, or an unwanted number. RegExps can be used to *validate* the string.

Comment: Yes, though if parseFloat return a `NaN` that would probably mean that it's not a valid number.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make the decimal point and 1 or 2 digits after the decimal point into its own optional group:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

---

Tests:

```
> var re = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
  undefined
> re.test('123')
  true
> re.test('123.00')
  true
> re.test('123.')
  false
> re.test('12.34.5')
  false
> re.test('123.000')
  false
```

Comment: +1 this is what I came up with too... except my browser decided to hang as I was posting it :(

Comment: what do you do when you have 100,000.00 ?

Comment: @maazza handling such input was not part of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

The `?` makes the group `(\.\d{1, 2})` optional (i.e., matches 0 or 1 times).

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
// Check if string is currency
var isCurrency_re    = /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d\d)?)|(\.\d\d))\s*$/;
function isCurrency (s) {
   return String(s).search (isCurrency_re) != -1
}
```